# TrackBar Control acting as a Range Selector with Multiple Thumbs

Tags: c#, .net, controls, range, trackbar

I am after a control which works similarly to a TrackBar control but has three thumbs, one for selecting a value and two others for selecting the minimum and maximum values on the same control.

I have searched Google for this and I have found a lot of people asking for the same thing (or similar range control) but I haven't found any resources showing how to do this or examples of code.

Does anyone know if I can find a resource for this? If not.. How would I go about creating a control like this?

Many thanks for any information or advice you can provide me with.

Comment: [C#-RangeBar-control](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=2275),

[A-custom-range-selector-control-in-C#-with-a-little](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28717/A-custom-range-selector-control-in-C-with-a-little)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will need a extensive answer with code.. so i will only give you an approach.

You will need to make an custom control to do this.. you can inherit the trackbar control and Extend it to make two more Thumbs and then attach a drag event to make dragging. On Drag Event Set the Trackbar's  Maximum and Minimum properties.

Fisrt try this approach.. if you face any problem ask it here for that specific answer.